# How to setup AWS Load Balancing between two EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am using aws server. There is two EC2 instance with same code. How can I set up of load balance so that when one ec2 is down than traffic automatically moves to another ec2 instance.

Comment: This is well documented by aws at https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/ depending upon the choice of your load balancer type, you’ll need to follow from the document. Apart from AWS services, you can also choose solutions like HAProxy and Nginx, those will be managed by you.

Comment: All AWS load balancers perform health checks and will only serve traffic to instances that pass the health check. So, if one instance fails, the load balancer will stop sending traffic to that instance, but will continue sending traffic to the other instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a classic loadbalancer or an application load balancer depending on your requirement.
You can go to [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com) -> [Ec2](https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2) -> LoadBalancer and create a load balancer from there.

Later you can register both your instances under that load balancer. Create an Alias record for your Loadbalancer and point your application URL or Website URL to the Loadbalancer DNS. This will make sure that the requests coming to to your Load Balancer get distributed among both Ec2 instances equally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set up until load balance and register both instance to it. but not getting idea about creating Alias record. Can you please describe in brief ?